# What are java compatible portable database engines?

Tags: java, database

Which free databases are suitable for creating ~100,000 record table?

I want to write a Java text editor with native English-Georgian dictionary.

Comment: have a look at this one: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 2):

JAVA is compatible for all database there is no restriction for that.
if you are looking for free one

```
RDMS:MYSQL,orcale
NOSQL:mongoDb
```